# Using react datepicker, need to apply different styles for today's date and selected date

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using React Datepicker and I need to apply two different styles for the current date and a selected date.

I have a style for the current date and a style for when a user selects a date.

My problem is that neither style takes precedent over the other and when you select the current date both colors just mesh. I'm trying to set it so that when you select the current date the selected date CSS style is applied and the other style is ignored.

[image: Edit blue-bash-32xik]

```
CSS Styles
```

```
.myClassname,
.react-datepicker__day--selected {
  background-color: #1648c3 !important;
}

.myClassname,
.react-datepicker__day--today {
  border: 2px solid
    linear-gradient(
      174deg,
      rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.7357317927170868) 32%,
      rgba(249, 239, 170, 1) 100%
    );
  border-radius: 0.3rem;
  background: linear-gradient(
    174deg,
    rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.7357317927170868) 32%,
    rgba(249, 239, 170, 1) 100%
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have o change is in your `selected` CSS selector. Instead of setting the `background-color` attribute, set just `background` attribute. That will override the `background: linear-gradient` from today selector.

```css
myClassname,
.react-datepicker__day--selected {
  background: #1648c3 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @aquilesb's answer

```
.react-datepicker__day--keyboard-selected {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

This style can also be added for convenience.